# Relation for Dirac-spinors of different helicities

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors

Assume that we have massless spin-1/2 particles. The Dirac-spinor is the solution of the Dirac equation:

$$ p^\mu \gamma_\mu u_\pm(p) = 0, \quad p^2 = 0$$

The subscripts $\pm$ denote two different solutions, belonging to two different helicities. Is it possible to find a representation for the $\gamma_\mu$ so that the following relation holds true?

$$ u_+ = \left( u_- \right)^* $$

I know this possible for (polarization) vectors, i.e. one may choose $\epsilon^\mu_+ = \left( \epsilon^\mu_- \right)^* $, but I guess it is not for spinors (in the weyl representation it obviously is not). So here is my

**Question:** Is it possible to find a representation of the Dirac-Gamma-matrices so that the spinors of different helicities are related by complex conjugation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For massless particles, helicity coincides with chirality thus you ask to find
the basis such that
$$
\psi_{\pm}=\left(  \psi_{\mp}\right)  ^{\star},\quad\gamma_{5}\psi_{\pm}%
=\pm\psi_{\pm}.
$$
Using the decomposition of hermitian operator:
$$
\left(  \gamma_{5}\right)  _{ij}=\left(  \psi_{+}\right)  _{i}\left(  \psi
_{+}^{\star}\right)  _{j}-\left(  \psi_{-}\right)  _{i}\left(  \psi_{-}%
^{\star}\right)  _{j}=\left(  \psi_{+}\right)  _{i}\left(  \psi_{-}\right)
_{j}-\left(  \psi_{-}\right)  _{i}\left(  \psi_{+}\right)  _{j},
$$
we find that $\gamma_{5}$ should be an antisymmetric matrix. Since
$\gamma_{5}$ is a hermitian operator it implies that all components of
$\gamma_{5}$ should be pure imaginary. In [Majorana basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Majorana_basis) all $\gamma$-matrices
are pure imaginary and since
$$
\gamma_{5}=i\gamma^{0}\gamma^{1}\gamma^{2}\gamma^{3},
$$
it means that $\gamma_{5}$ is also pure imaginary (and thus antisymmetric):
$$
\gamma_{5}=\left(
\begin{array}
[c]{cc}
\sigma_{2} & \\
& -\sigma_{2}%
\end{array}
\right)  .
$$

**Update. Off topic.** From my personal point of view, I would never use the basis of the polarization wave function such that $\psi_{j,m}^{\star}=\psi_{j,-m}$. The reason is the following: sometimes it is extremely convenient (see explanation below) to associate $\psi^{\star}$ with the «time-revesed» wave function as it is suggested by the Schrödinger equation and the anti-unitary nature of the operation of time reversal. The polarization wave function of a particle of spin $s>0$ is a contravariant rank $2s$ symmetric spinor:
$$
\psi_{s,\sigma}=\phi^{i_{1}..i_{2s}},
$$
in whose indices $1$ occurs $s+\sigma$ times and $2$ $s-\sigma$ times. The
complex conjugation leads to the covariant spinor:
$$
\phi_{i_{1}\ldots i_{2s}}^{\left(  rev\right)  }=\left(  \phi^{i_{1}..i_{2s}%
}\right)  ^{\star}.
$$
Using the antisymmetric tensor $\epsilon^{ij}$ (the metric tensor for
$SU\left(  2\right)  $) one can construct again a covariant spinor, so that the sign
changes as many times as there are twos among the indices:
$$
\psi_{s,-\sigma}^{\left(  rev\right)  }=T\left(  \psi_{s,\sigma}\right)
=\psi_{s,\sigma}^{\star}\left(  -1\right)  ^{s-\sigma}.
$$
For example, when the time-reversal operation is repeated:
$$
T^{2}\left(  \psi_{s,\sigma}\right)  =\left(  -1\right)  ^{2s}\psi_{s,\sigma},
$$
that immediately leads to the well-known Kramers' theorem:

> For a system with the half-integral sum of the spins of particles, in
>   an arbitrary electric field, all the levels must be doubly degenerate,
>   and complex conjugate spinors correspond to two different states with
>   the same energy.

For details, see § 60, **L.D. Landau and E.M. Lifshitz**, *Quantum Mechanics,
Non-relativistic Theory.*

Therefore a (polarization) wave function with is usually normalized by the
condition:
$$
\psi_{j,m}^{\star}=\psi_{j,-m}\left(  -1\right)  ^{s-\sigma}.\quad\quad(1)
$$
For example, for $s=1$ the polarization vectors have the form:
$$
\varepsilon_{\pm1}=\frac{\mp i}{\sqrt{2}}\left(  1,\pm i,0\right)
,\quad\varepsilon_{0}=i\left(  0,0,1\right)  ,
$$
see also Eqs. (28.7-28.9) in **L.D. Landau and E.M. Lifshitz**, *Quantum Mechanics,
Non-relativistic Theory.* However, some people find the normalization (1) too complicated.

Answer (score 3):

This is called a Majorana representation, in your convention for the gamma matrices, you make sure that all the gamma matrices are pure imaginary.